# Sitecore Upload Media from Page editor doesn't work

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-media-library, page-editor, sitecore7.2

I am a new bee to Sitecore and here comes my first challenge at work.
In one of the website component, I want to add an image.

For this in content editor:

1. I'll click on browse.
2. Switch to folder view.
3. Navigate down to the folder you want to save into.
4. Click upload media on top left.
5. Click ‘Browse for media files’ and navigate to the image on the local drive and select it.
6. Enter alt-text and click upload media.
7. In Chrome the green bar for uploading never seems to finish. On IE one of the green bars changes to ‘Upload complete’. At this point there is no call to action to add the image to the module, select the module – you just don’t know what to do next.
8. Eventually you have to click ‘Back’ or ‘close’. Then when you go to find the image it is not in the folder you selected. It is in Upload folder. We cannot keep all of our files in ‘Upload’. We need to be able to upload into a chosen folder.

I am using Sitecore 7.2.

This works properly in a base site in Sitecore 7.2, but is not working in my website. 
Is there any setting I need to change to make this work properly?

I know we can add media files into Media library directly and can use it. But we want to do it the using the above mentioned steps/ or using Page editor. The main problem is, this doesn't work while adding image from Page editor.

Hope I can get some solution!

many thanks!

Comment: Hey Chethan, what is the size of the file? Check the log files that it might have some helpful info

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Sitecore, i remcommend you contact Sitecore support about it

Comment: It works fine for me on a clean Sitecore install, so something you have customised possibly... any JS errors in the developer console? Also, did you change Destination Folder before you upload? http://imgur.com/cMvHstb

Comment: This is not a bug in Sitecore, as it does not occur in a clean instance. However, it could be that your instance is corrupted or unpacked in a weird way. If all else fails, I would install a clean instance of Sitecore and try to get your site running on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the [Release Notes](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx) for Sitecore 7.2 and found that there were several bugs related to Media Uploads that were resolved in Update 2 (140526), including some that relate to choosing the destination of uploaded media. From your description of the issue and the bugs that were fixed in Update 2, it sounds like you may only need to update to Revision 140526.

To find out what revision of Sitecore you are using, go to the *Sitecore Desktop -> Start Menu -> Control Panel -> Administration -> Show About Sitecore Information*. As you will see in the screenshot, below, there is a parenthesized revision number at the top. If that number is not 140526 then you should try to apply Update 2 to your instance.

[image]

Note that this screenshot is of an instance that is not running on Sitecore 7.2 Update 2, but is instead running on the initial release (140228).

Comment: Thanks for the response Zachary.  Yes I am using rev 140526, and this problem exists in this revision.  Like others have mentioned I tested this in a new instance of Sitecore which is of same rev, and it works fine there. May be I will check logs like @Snapper has mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Zachary you are right! My bad, since, I was working in multiple VM's I got the Version number wrong, the issue was in 140228 revision. And after I went through the release notes of Sitecore 7.2 update 2, I found that there are lot of fix and enhancements to Media upload functionality.

Comment: hey @ChethanSriram , did you find any fix for this? really appreciate if you can share that with us. many thanks :)